# Finding a value in an Array?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I am trying to search for the value in an array. The results keep coming back as nothing though. I am assuming my loop isnt proper, could you assist me in what i am doing wrong?? It is suppose to use the value held in "searchFor" and match up. Then display the value in Printer.printPersonList.

```
    public static ArrayList<Person> findPerson(String searchFor) {
    ArrayList<Person> matches = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Person p : personList) {
        boolean isAMatch = false;

        if (p.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchFor)) {
            isAMatch = true;

        } else if (p.getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchFor)) {
            isAMatch = true;

        } else if (p.getSocialSecurityNumber().contains(searchFor)) {
            isAMatch = true;
            ;
        } else if (String.format("%d", p.getAge()).equals(searchFor))
            if (isAMatch) {

                matches.add(p);
            }

        Printer.printPersonList(matches);

    }
    return matches;

}
```

---

This is from printer.java

```
public static void printPersonList(ArrayList<Person> personListToPrint) {

    System.out
            .printf("\nLast Name           First Name           Social Security Number  Age\n");
    System.out
            .printf("=================== ===================  ======================  ===\n");
    for (Person p : personListToPrint) {

        System.out.printf("%-20s%-21s%-24s%s\n", p.getLastName(),
                p.getLastName(), p.getSocialSecurityNumber(), p.getAge());

    }
```

Comment: `else if (String.format("%d", p.getAge()).equals(searchFor))` has no meaningful body.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your algorithm is that you are setting `isAMatch` as true if the Person's first name is equal to the key that you are searching for, but not adding the person to the list. Here's the segment that's flawed:

```
...code omitted...

} else if (String.format("%d", p.getAge()).equals(searchFor))
            if (isAMatch) {

                matches.add(p);
            }

        Printer.printPersonList(matches);

    }

...code omitted...
```

The `if(isAMatch)` code is only executed if `String.format("%d", p.getAge()).equals(searchFor)` - there are no open/close parentheses afterwards to indicate a code block.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing some code.  Right now, a match will only be added if the age matches and `isAMatch` is already `true`.  You'll probably want to change

```
} else if (String.format("%d", p.getAge()).equals(searchFor))
    if (isAMatch) {
        matches.add(p);
    }
```

to

```
} else if (String.format("%d", p.getAge()).equals(searchFor)) {
    isAMatch = true;
}
if (isAMatch) {
    matches.add(p);
}
```

Comment: still displays nothing :(

Comment: At this point you'll need to determine whether `personList` contains any items, and ensure that your search should find something by checking the data in each `Person`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281105/project-will-not-display-search-results 

:(

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like that :

```
public static ArrayList<Person> findPerson(String searchFor) {
    ArrayList<Person> matches = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Person p : personList) {
        boolean isAMatch = false;

        if (p.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchFor)) {
            isAMatch = true;

        } else if (p.getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchFor)) {
            isAMatch = true;

        } else if (p.getSocialSecurityNumber().contains(searchFor)) {
            isAMatch = true;

        } else if (String.format("%d", p.getAge()).equals(searchFor)) {
           isAMatch = true;
            }

        if (isAMatch) {

                matches.add(p);
            }
    }
    Printer.printPersonList(matches);
    return matches;

}
```

I modified the last `else if` statement, and displaced the `Printer` method call out of the `for` loop.