# Project will not display search results

Tags: java

I have this project ive been working on all week and cannot get the search in Main.java in the switch case 3 to work. Any idea why this will not display??

Here it all is :(

Main.Java

```
package hartman;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Printer.printWelcome();

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean keepRunning = true;
    while (keepRunning) {
        Printer.printMenu();
        Printer.printPrompt("Please enter your operation: ");

        String userSelection = keyboard.nextLine();

        switch (userSelection) {
        case "1":
            Database.addPerson(personList);
            break;
        case "2":
            Database.printDatabase(personList);
            break;
        case "3":
            Printer.printSearchPersonTitle();
            String searchFor = keyboard.nextLine();
            Database.findPerson(searchFor);
            Printer.printPersonList(personList);
            break;
        case "4":
            keepRunning = false;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    Printer.printGoodBye();
    keyboard.close();
}

}
```

Database.Java

```
package hartman;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Database {
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
private static ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();

public Database() {

}

public static void addPerson(ArrayList<Person> personList) {
    Printer.printAddPersonTitle();
    Printer.printPrompt("  Enter first name: ");
    String addFirstName = keyboard.nextLine();

    Printer.printPrompt("  Enter last Name: ");
    String addLastName = keyboard.nextLine();

    Printer.printPrompt("  Enter social Security Number: ");
    String addSocial = keyboard.nextLine();

    Printer.printPrompt("  Enter year of birth: ");
    int addYearBorn = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());

    System.out.printf("\n%s, %s saved!\n", addFirstName, addLastName);
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setFirstName(addFirstName);
    person.setLastName(addLastName);
    person.setSocialSecurityNumber(addSocial);
    person.setYearBorn(addYearBorn);
    personList.add(person);
}

public static void printDatabase(ArrayList<Person> personList) {
    System.out
            .printf("\nLast Name           First Name           Social Security Number  Age\n");
    System.out
            .printf("=================== ===================  ======================  ===\n");
    for (Person p : personList) {

        System.out.printf("%-20s%-21s%-24s%s\n", p.getLastName(),
                p.getLastName(), p.getSocialSecurityNumber(), p.getAge());

    }

}

public static ArrayList<Person> findPerson(String searchFor) {
    ArrayList<Person> matches = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Person p : personList) {
        boolean isAMatch = false;

        if (p.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchFor)) {
            isAMatch = true;

        } else if (p.getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchFor)) {
            isAMatch = true;

        } else if (p.getSocialSecurityNumber().contains(searchFor)) {
            isAMatch = true;
            ;
        } else if (String.format("%d", p.getAge()).equals(searchFor)) {
            isAMatch = true;
        }
        if (isAMatch) {
            matches.add(p);
        }
        Printer.printPersonList(matches);
    }

    return matches;

}

}
```

Person.Java

```
package hartman;

public class Person {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String socialSecurityNumber;
private int yearBorn;

public Person() {

}

public Person(String firstName, String lastName,
        String socialSecurityNumber, int yearBorn) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.socialSecurityNumber = socialSecurityNumber;
    this.yearBorn = yearBorn;

}

public int getAge() {
    return yearBorn = 2014 - yearBorn;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getSocialSecurityNumber() {
    return socialSecurityNumber;
}

public void setSocialSecurityNumber(String socialSecurityNumber) {
    this.socialSecurityNumber = socialSecurityNumber;
}

public int getYearBorn() {
    return yearBorn;
}

public void setYearBorn(int yearBorn) {
    this.yearBorn = yearBorn;
}
}
```

Printer.Java

```
package hartman;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Printer {

public static void printWelcome() {
    System.out.printf("WELCOME TO PERSON DATABASE!\n");
}

public static void printGoodBye() {
    System.out.printf("\nGOOD BYE!!\n");
}

public static void printMenu() {
    System.out.printf("\nMain Menu\n");
    System.out.printf("---------\n\n");
    System.out.printf("  1. Add a new Person to the database.\n");
    System.out.printf("  2. Print the database.\n");
    System.out.printf("  3. Search for a person in the database.\n");
    System.out.printf("  4. Exit the application.\n");
    System.out.printf("\n");
}

public static void printPrintMenu() {
    System.out.printf("Print\n\n");
}

public static void printAddPersonTitle() {
    System.out.printf("\nAdd Person to Database\n\n");

}

public static void printPrompt(String promptForWhat) {
    System.out.printf("%s", promptForWhat);
}

public static void printPersonSaved(Person personSaved) {
    System.out.printf("%s", personSaved);
}

public static void printSearchPersonTitle() {
    System.out.printf("\nSearch for Person in Database\n\n");
    System.out.printf("Enter search value: ");
}

public static void printPersonList(ArrayList<Person> personListToPrint) {

    System.out
            .printf("\nLast Name           First Name           Social Security Number  Age\n");
    System.out
            .printf("=================== ===================  ======================  ===\n");
    for (Person p : personListToPrint) {

        System.out.printf("%-20s%-21s%-24s%s\n", p.getLastName(),
                p.getLastName(), p.getSocialSecurityNumber(), p.getAge());

    }


}
}
```

Any help would be great... im about to break my pc and give up.

Comment: what is your java runtime version?

Comment: newest one available. why

Comment: Aren't you throwing away the result of the search? `Database.findPerson(searchFor);` `findPerson` returns an ArrayList of `Person`s but you don't do anything with the result. You should probably add the result to `personList`

Comment: print `java -version`

Comment: Any ideas? I am not sure what you mean mav..

Comment: Nothing to do with java. Your code is simply wrong. You're adding an empty list as a Person object ? A `personList` is not a `Person`.

Comment: Follow basic OOP concepts.

Comment: I dont even know what that is

Answer (score 0):

The problems is that you are using the static instance from DataBase

```
ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

I was gonna say follow the rules of OOP [click here if you want to learn](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/)

But since you already started a lot of coding ill try to answer your problem..

Dont use instance of `personList` in the DataBase. Just use from the Main class.

**here is where the problem started:**

```
for (Person p : personList)
```

You are using an empty ArrayList from DataBase class..
The one that has data and you are using is from the Main class..

**solution:**

Remove the

`private static ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();`

from your DataBase then do this in you Main Class

```
 public class Main {
  public static ArrayList<Person> personList;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Printer.printWelcome();

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

**and change the for loop to:**

```
for (Person p : Main.personList)
```

This is what you get when you dont use OOP on your problems its soo ugly and complicated..
Its better when it is object oriented.. P.S. learn that..